# TypeError: 'OrientRecord' object does not support indexing

Tags: python, pyorient

I'm trying to extract records from an Oriented DB using `pyorient` and here is my query:

```
query =  "SELECT value FROM (SELECT expand(Elements) FROM dataset) WHERE type = 'XXX'"
records = client.command(query)
```

and everything is working fine. When I try to print records, here is what I get:

```
record = records[0]
print type(record)
<class 'pyorient.otypes.OrientRecord'>


print record
{{'value': 'Name'},'version':0,'rid':'#-2:0'}
```

and since I just need to extract '`Name`' from `record`, I tried:

```
print record[0]
```

and got

```
TypeError: 'OrientRecord' object does not support indexing
```

and here is the results of `repr`:

```
print(repr(record))
<pyorient.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x7fdcdb531ad0>
```

Comment: could you show the result of `print repr(record)`?

Comment: @TadhgMcDonald-Jensen: Thanks for the comments. It is updated.

Comment: what about `record.__o_storage`, what type does that return?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

After looking at the source code I figured out how to access the various parts of the data from the string representation:

```
>>> x
<pyorient.otypes.OrientRecord object at 0x105789e48>
>>> print(x)
{{'value': 'Name'},'version':0,'rid':'#-2:0'}
>>> x.oRecordData
{'value': 'Name'}
>>> x.value #allow for access in the oRecordData as attributes?
'Name'
>>> x._version, x._rid #other values in string representation
(0, '#-2:0')
```

I'm fairly disappointed that the string representation didn't make this apparent.  Anyway I think you want the `x.oRecordData` one.